# How to listen to color changes on the color picker?

Tags: widgets, jquery, admin, core

I am trying to run some custom jquery function every time the colorpicker's color change. The colorpicker is include as part of the WP core. I have been looking at the JS code, but I can't figure out what's the trigger that updates the color.

I have tried listening for several classes, and also listening for changes on the text input (the one that holds the color hex value), but no luck.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 7):

I hate answering my own question, but hopefully this can help someone else with similar issues:

Wordpress uses Iris color picker.
http://automattic.github.io/Iris/#

Wordpress also creates a jquery widget with default settings for Iris.
The file can be found under wp-admin/js/color-picker.js

At first I was trying to pass values directly to iris(), which works, but that overrides the wordpress widget.

Once I found out about the widget, I wrote the following:

```
$(".wp-color-picker").wpColorPicker(
  'option',
  'change',
  function(event, ui) {
    //do something on color change here
  }
);
```

The wpColirPicker accepts a custom function for the change event. So it runs first the default actions and then it allows you to add your own.

Answer (score 1):

As **gdaniel** was saying in his answer, WordPress uses [Iris](http://automattic.github.io/Iris/) color picker. You can pass your callbacks to wpColorPicker plugin using **change** and **clear** options. Please note that change-callback will handle all the changes except for cleaning of the field via "Clear" button. So use clear-callback for that purposes.

```
jQuery('.wp-color-picker').wpColorPicker({
    /**
     * @param {Event} event - standard jQuery event, produced by whichever
     * control was changed.
     * @param {Object} ui - standard jQuery UI object, with a color member
     * containing a Color.js object.
     */
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var element = event.target;
        var color = ui.color.toString();

        // Add your code here
    },

    /**
     * @param {Event} event - standard jQuery event, produced by "Clear"
     * button.
     */
    clear: function (event) {
        var element = jQuery(event.target).siblings('.wp-color-picker')[0];
        var color = '';

        if (element) {
            // Add your code here
        }
    }
});
```

Please also note that if you use *element.value* in your change-callback then you'll get the old value instead of new one.